# Laravel "orWhere" not working as expected

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I must be missing something obvious here.

Say I have a `searchTerm` variable set to "%Arrival%".

I have the following code:

`$results = $app->screeners()->where('title', 'LIKE', $searchTerm)->get()`

My `$results` array now holds one object that has the `title` "Arrival".

Now, if I run the following code:

`$results = $app->screeners()->where('title', 'LIKE', $searchTerm)->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', $searchTerm)->get();`

I get an empty array.

Can someone explain how adding an "or" clause is removing results?

Answer (score 5):

By default, Laravel will add a where condition to restrict queries to only return records whose `deleted_at` attribute is `null`.  The where clause that is being generated for your query probably resembles something like this:

```
WHERE `table_name`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `title` LIKE ? OR `description` LIKE ?
```

I'm not sure why this query would not include your previous result from only restricting the query to the `title` column, but you can see the actual SQL being generated by removing the call to `->get()` and adding a `dd($results->toSql())`. This may help you debug further.

I think what you really want to do is have the two and conditions you want to apply to the query be nested, something along these lines:

```
WHERE `table_name`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND (`title` LIKE ? OR `description` LIKE ?)
```

You can achieve this by passing a closure to `where`:

```
$results = $app->screeners()->where(function($query) use($searchTerm) {
    // Notice also the addition of the placeholder ('%') character
    $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
        ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
    ;
})->get();
```

Comment: Well, that new version certainly works, though I still can't quite understand why mine wouldn't work. Also I should have mentioned that my $searchTerm variable was actually %Arraival%, just stripped some code out accidentally!

Comment: @Rail24 I think, given that a query gets preloaded with a `WHERE` condition already comes in to play. Just adding another `OR` clause is not just going to work as you would expect it to. If you can post the SQL that is actually being generated, the answer to that question may become much more clearer.

Comment: This is the statement it spits out: `select * from "screeners" where "screener_application_ids" = ? and ("title" LIKE ? or "description" LIKE ?)`